# 2005 Suzuki Katana stalls when put in gear

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, suzuki, stall, katana

I have reworked all the carborators on the motorcycle. All seemed well but once it was put in gear, it stalled. What do I need to look for?

Comment: Start by checking for vacuum leaks after the carburetors.

Answer (score 3):

There is a sidestand switch that kills the motor if you attempt to put it into gear with the sidestand down, it's a safety measure.  Check that switch at the top of your sidestand to see if the a mount bolt or nut has fallen out thereby loosening the switch and making the vehicle inoperable when you put it into gear.